# _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC not showing file name

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks, crtdbg.h

I am trying to detect memory leak, and I am using make _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC macro to locate where the leaks area. So I am defining MACRO like following:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
    #define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

In my code, I have:

```
UINT SomeFunThread( LPVOID pParam )
{
   _CrtMemState crtMemStateStart;
    _CrtMemState crtMemStateFinish;

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&crtMemStateStart);


    // My suspisious code


     _CrtMemCheckpoint(&crtMemStateFinish);

      int nDifference(0);
      _CrtMemState crtMemStateDifference;
      nDifference = _CrtMemDifference(&crtMemStateDifference, &crtMemStateStart, &crtMemStateFinish);

    if(nDifference > 0)
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```

(Thanks to Tushar Jadhav: [Memory consumption increases quickly, then drops very slowly; memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577638/memory-consumption-increases-quickly-then-drops-very-slowly-memory-leak))

But the output shows something like:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{124058} normal block at 0x0000000031DED080, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < 0      ` $     > C8 30 F7 EF FE 07 00 00 60 D2 24 1D 00 00 00 00
```

instead of something like this:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
C:\PROGRAM FILES\VISUAL STUDIO\MyProjects\leaktest\leaktest.cpp(20) : {18} 
normal block at 0x00780E80, 64 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

So how can I make this show the file name and location of the leak?

Comment: The code that allocates just wasn't compiled with your #defines in effect.  Could be located in a library, could be in a DLL like the prebuilt C++ template class specializations.  Or the DLL that contains the code got unloaded before the leak report was generated.

Comment: @HansPassant   So are you say that it was not my "suspicious code" itself that leaks; it was some code/bianraies/dlls that get called within "suspicious code" ?

Comment: I'd say it is code you haven't found, could be anywhere.  The usual problem with leaks, isn't it?  If you can get the number between {braces} to repeat then set _crtBreakAlloc to that number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the line of the leak only is displayed if the CRT is turned on in that cpp file.

Comment: Is there a quick way of turning on CRT in all files without, e.g. creating a new header with the defines in it and including it everywhere?

Comment: Seconding  aquirdturtle's question: it looks like all code in my software starts off including "stdafx.h" so I added these three lines after the "TODO" comment, and rebuilt.  It wasn't sufficient.

`// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here`
`#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC`
`#include <stdlib.h>`
`#include <crtdbg.h>`

Answer (score 11):

In my case I ended up including the stuff from [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?482410-Memory-leaks-doesn-t-print-location) thread into my code. This overrides the `new` operator and includes the name of the file and the line number into it for later printing. Not sure if this is applicable to Visual Studio only.

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

The whole test code from the referenced source is:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include<iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

int main() 
{
    char *a = new char[10];
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0; 
}
```

which in my test case prints:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
e:\test\testapplication\testapplication.cpp(11) : {144} normal block at 0x007F4EF0, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <          > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```