# Visual Studio memory leak detection not printing file name and line number

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, crtdbg.h

I want to check my program for memory leaks and found [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I thoroughly followed the article and added

```
#define CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

and

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

when the program exits.

It properly dumps all the memory leak info in my output window, but here's the problem:

**It doesn't print the file name and line number where the memory leaks are!**

It says in the article that with `#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` it prints the file name and line number, but it doesn't for me.

My output looks like this

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{3456} normal block at 0x038F81E8, 560 bytes long.
 Data: <       A       B> 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 41 00 00 00 FF 00 00 E6 42 
{3447} normal block at 0x038F8170, 56 bytes long.
 Data: < B    ^  B      > 80 42 90 03 10 02 5E 08 80 42 90 03 00 00 CD CD 
{3440} normal block at 0x038F86B0, 840 bytes long.
 Data: <       A       B> 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 41 00 00 00 FF 00 00 A8 42 
...
```

So I can't really work with that... also pressing F4 to go to the line doesn't work.

Could you please help me?

Comment: If you've got a debug build, try running the application under [Application Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps if u havent figured out @A.D, works for win32 applications, we need to override the new operator. unfortunately it doesnot work for MFC application.:(

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include<iostream>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
int main() 
{
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF ) ;
char *a = new char[10];
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works for a simple program like that, but won't even compile for my MFC/WTL app

Answer (score 1):

You `#define` is wrong.  In order to get the format of

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
C:\PROGRAM FILES\VISUAL STUDIO\MyProjects\leaktest\leaktest.cpp(20) : {18} 
normal block at 0x00780E80, 64 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

You need to use:

```
#define _DEBUG 
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
```

You have to include `_DEBUG` as well since `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` is only available with `_DEBUG` defined([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10t349zs.aspx)).
Also from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107713/crtdbg-map-alloc-not-showing-file-name) make sure that the `#define` is in the cpp file you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in the VS2013 documention sample at the top. It should be:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
```

Note the leading underscore. The VS2005/2008 document use `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` and the VS2013 document references `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` later on.

A few other things you can check:

- Make sure you are in the Debug build
- Clean/rebuild your application
- If you are using a precompiled header make sure you add the `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` definition to `stdafx.h`

Comment: I tried that too but it still won't show the file name and line number